# Nginx serve static response message body?

Tags: nginx

I'd like to make nginx work like fast responser for special queries.

```
location /app {
  # server static response message body (10 bytes)
}
```

How can I do that? It is needed for POST requests

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add text to `return` directive.

```
return 200 Text;
```

Binary data could be put literally. E.g. in vim I could type `ctrl-v 001` to have:

```
return 200 "[.]";
#            ^--- \001 symbol here.
```

and result:

```
$ curl -s http://localhost:2002/ | xxd
0000000: 5b01 5d                                  [.]
#          ^^ here it is
```

But I think it's better to serve static binary file or use embedded lua or perl. E.g. with lua:

```
content_by_lua 'ngx.print("[\001]")';
```

will give the same result as above, but config doesn't have some weird unprintable characters.

Comment: Is there a way to push binary data to that "Text"?